# filtering the records in the second grid according to the selection in the first in .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

which control can i use?, how to do this .Net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581796.aspx)

Comment: +1.  In case the asker objects that they want to use a Gridview for the "details view", this works just fine with a Gridview in place of the DetailsView.  I use this pattern all the time when using parent-child records.  (I also like the nested repeater approach when it's read-only, but this works good where the master and/or details need to be edited.